# Can I create Domain classes in separate Java Project and import in Grails

Tags: grails

Just for flexibility and not to be tied up with Grails, I wish to create domains on a separate java project and import the domain classes in Grails project.  Is that possible?  I am thinking the Java project will just contain POJO and maybe hibernate mapping to database.

I wish to be able to use the usual save delete and find* functionalities if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use also plain Java project as a domain model - see [grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#hibernate](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#hibernate)

Basically you put there your domain classes together with Hibernate mapping (XML or annotation-based) and pack it into jar, which is then added as a dependency to the grails app.

Your domain classes will be enhanced with standard GORM methods (findBy, save..) just as if they were GORM domain classes. We have used this model a long time in our projects.

Comment: I did not know it will be automatic. I dont need to do any wiring? It will magically treat them like Grails domain classes?

Comment: Not magically - it's linked by the hibernate.cfg.xml file that should contain the mappings. In case you use annotations, it' even more straightforward - annotated classes are automatically taken as they were standard GORM domain classes..

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a separate plugin project which contains the domain classes. And if you want to use it in your grails project then just add following in your BuildConfig.groovy

```
grails.plugin.location.YourDomainClassProjectName= "../YourDomainClassProjectName"
```

And add that project from build path. Right click on project from navigator - > Properties -> Java Build Path -> Project  ... and add your project here.

Comment: Hi, but that plugin project is still Grails right?  What I was thinking is just Java project not Grails.

Comment: Yes you can use that.